# How to fix Asynctask error caused by Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "pets"

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm getting this error:

> ​Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "pets" while trying to insert data into the database. While clicking on the insert option on the mainActivity it was supposed to insert data into the database and show that data into MainActivity but cuz of the error my application is getting crashed. How to solve this error? The error is caused in PetProvider query's Pet_ID at selection args point.

The code of PetProvider is shown below:

> `2021-12-12 02:21:07.435 11934-11959/com.example.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
> Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 11934
>
> java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
>
> at android.os.AsyncTask$4.done(AsyncTask.java:415)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "pets"
>
> at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:594)
> at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:636)
> at android.content.ContentUris.parseId(ContentUris.java:89)
> at com.example.myapplication.data.PetProvider.query(PetProvider.java:100)
> at android.content.ContentProvider.query(ContentProvider.java:1379)
> at android.content.ContentProvider.query(ContentProvider.java:1475)
> at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:278)
> at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:1185)
> at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:1116)
> at android.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:71)
> at android.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:46)
> at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader.onLoadInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:321)
> at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:74)
> at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:62)
> at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:394)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923) 
>  package com.example.myapplication.data;

```
    import android.content.ContentProvider;
    import android.content.ContentResolver;
    import android.content.ContentUris;
    import android.content.ContentValues;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.UriMatcher;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    
    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
    import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
    
    import java.nio.file.Path;
    
    
    public class PetProvider extends ContentProvider {
    
        private PetdbHepler petdbHepler;
        public static String CONTENT_AUTHORITY = "com.example.myapplication";
    
        //To make this a usable URI, we use the parse method which takes in a URI string and returns a Uri.
        public static Uri BASE_CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + CONTENT_AUTHORITY);
    
        //This constants stores the path for each of the tables which will be appended to the base content URI.
    
        public static final String PATH_PETS = "pets";
    
        public static final String LOG_TAG = PetProvider.class.getSimpleName();
    
    
        /**
         * URI matcher code for the content URI for the pets table
         */
        private static final int PETS = 100;
    
        /**
         * URI matcher code for the content URI for a single pet in the pets table
         */
        private static final int PET_ID = 101;
    
        /**
         * UriMatcher object to match a content URI to a corresponding code.
         * The input passed into the constructor represents the code to return for the root URI.
         * It's common to use NO_MATCH as the input for this case.
         */
        private static final UriMatcher sUriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
    
        // Static initializer. This is run the first time anything is called from this class.
        static {
            // The calls to addURI() go here, for all of the content URI patterns that the provider
            // should recognize. All paths added to the UriMatcher have a corresponding code to return
            // when a match is found.
    
            sUriMatcher.addURI(CONTENT_AUTHORITY, PATH_PETS, PETS);
            sUriMatcher.addURI(CONTENT_AUTHORITY, PATH_PETS + "/#", PET_ID);
    
        }
    
    
        @Override
        public boolean onCreate() {
            petdbHepler = new PetdbHepler(getContext());
            return false;
        }
    
        @Nullable
        @Override
        public Cursor query(@NonNull Uri uri, @Nullable String[] projection, @Nullable String selection, @Nullable String[] selectionArgs, @Nullable String sortOrder) {
            //steps To follow to query the database
            //first we nedd to get access to the database
            //second we need to pass the uri and check if the query is for whole table or for a single pet using uri matcher
            //atlast we need to switch according to the uri
            // so here is our code
    
            SQLiteDatabase database = petdbHepler.getReadableDatabase(); /*since we are only querying the database we need to use
                                                           getReadableDatabase and this step is to access the database which is first step*/
            Cursor cursor;
            int matcher = sUriMatcher.match(uri);//second we need to pass the uri and check if the query is for whole table or for a single pet using uri matcher
            switch (matcher) {
                case PETS:
                    cursor = database.query(Petcontract.PetsEntry.TABLE_NAME, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
                case PET_ID:
                    // For the PET_ID code, extract out the ID from the URI.
                    // For an example URI such as "content://com.example.android.pets/pets/3",
                    // the selection will be "_id=?" and the selection argument will be a
                    // String array containing the actual ID of 3 in this case.
                    //
                    // For every "?" in the selection, we need to have an element in the selection
                    // arguments that will fill in the "?". Since we have 1 question mark in the
                    // selection, we have 1 String in the selection arguments' String array.
    
    
                    selection = Petcontract.PetsEntry._ID + "?";
                    selectionArgs = new String[]{String.valueOf(ContentUris.parseId(uri))};
                    cursor = database.query(Petcontract.PetsEntry.TABLE_NAME, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
                    Log.e("PetProvider", "Hereis the problem");
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("cannot query unknown uri" + uri);
            }
            // Set notification URI on the Cursor,
            // so we know what content URI the Cursor was created for.
            // If the data at this URI changes, then we know we need to update the Cursor
            cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
            return cursor;
        }
    
        @Nullable
        @Override
        public String getType(@NonNull Uri uri) {
            return null;
        }
    
        @Nullable
        @Override
        public Uri insert(@NonNull Uri uri, @Nullable ContentValues contentValues) {
            final int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);
            switch (match) {
                case PETS:
                    return insertPet(uri, contentValues);
                default:
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Insertion is not supported for " + uri);
            }
        }
    
       private Uri insertPet(Uri uri, ContentValues contentValues){
           // Check that the name is not null
           String name = contentValues.getAsString(Petcontract.PetsEntry.COLUMN_NAME);
           if (name == null) {
               throw new IllegalArgumentException("Pet requires a name");
           }
    
           // Check that the gender is valid
           Integer gender = contentValues.getAsInteger(Petcontract.PetsEntry.COLUMN_GENDER);
           if (gender == null) {
               throw new IllegalArgumentException("Pet requires valid gender");
           }
    
           // If the weight is provided, check that it's greater than or equal to 0 kg
           Integer weight = contentValues.getAsInteger(Petcontract.PetsEntry.COLUMN_WEIGHT);
           if (weight != null && weight < 0) {
               throw new IllegalArgumentException("Pet requires valid weight");
           }
            SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = petdbHepler.getWritableDatabase();
            long id = sqLiteDatabase.insert(Petcontract.PetsEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
           // Notify all listeners that the data has changed for the pet content URI
           getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
    
           return  ContentUris.withAppendedId(Petcontract.PetsEntry.content_uri, id);
       }
    
    
        @Override
        public int delete(@NonNull Uri uri, @Nullable String selection, @Nullable String[] selectionArgs) {
            // Get writeable database
            SQLiteDatabase database =petdbHepler.getWritableDatabase();
            int rowsDeleted;
            final int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);
            switch (match) {
                case PETS:
                    // Delete all rows that match the selection and selection args
                    return database.delete(Petcontract.PetsEntry.TABLE_NAME, selection, selectionArgs);
                case PET_ID:
                    // Delete a single row given by the ID in the URI
                    selection = Petcontract.PetsEntry._ID + "=?";
                    selectionArgs = new String[] { String.valueOf(ContentUris.parseId(uri)) };
                    rowsDeleted = database.delete(Petcontract.PetsEntry.TABLE_NAME, selection, selectionArgs);
                    // If 1 or more rows were deleted, then notify all listeners that the data at the
                    // given URI has changed
                    if (rowsDeleted != 0) {
                        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
                        return database.delete(Petcontract.PetsEntry.TABLE_NAME, selection, selectionArgs);
                    }
                    else{
                        return rowsDeleted;
                    }
                default:
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Deletion is not supported for " + uri);
            }
    
        }
    
        @Override
        public int update(@NonNull Uri uri, @Nullable ContentValues values, @Nullable String selection, @Nullable String[] selectionArgs) {
            SQLiteDatabase database = petdbHepler.getWritableDatabase();
            int rowsUpdated = database.update(Petcontract.PetsEntry.TABLE_NAME, values, selection, selectionArgs);
    
            if (rowsUpdated != 0) {
                getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
                return rowsUpdated;
            }
            else
            {
                return database.update(Petcontract.PetsEntry.TABLE_NAME, values, selection, selectionArgs);
            }
        }
    }`
```

Comment: Well somewhere in your `query` method you're providing the string `pets` where a `long` is expected. Where's line `100` in your code?

Comment: selectionArgs = new String[]{String.valueOf(ContentUris.parseId(uri))};       it is line no 100

Answer (score 0):

```
Just add break after the case: Pet. The code is;
   case PETS:
                cursor = database.query(Petcontract.PetsEntry.TABLE_NAME, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
                break;  //dont't forget to add break statement in Pet case.
            case PET_ID:
```